# How do I run an extension command on startup on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I built a VSCode extension that consumes an external API. I need it to lunch a command to fetch some data every time a user opens VSCode.

I have read the documentation, but I don't find an answer.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 22):

```
"activationEvents": [ "onStartupFinished" ]
```

This is much better then "*", it means the same thing besides it won't distract startup of your VS Code

Comment: Hi, would you happen to know a way to make this a setting for the extension, rather than manifested behavior?

Answer (score 16):

I had a misconception about how an extension's life cycle worked. Finally, I've been able to solve my problem. Here is how:

On the extension's `package.json` you have the `activationEvents` setting. This setting establishes WHEN your extension will be activated. You can read about the different options in the official docs, but let me tell you that one of the options is the star operator `*`.

If you set this in you `package.json`:

```
"activationEvents": [
    "*"
],
```

Your extension will activate when VSCode is opened.

What happens when your extension is activated? **It will fire the `activate` function, defined by default in the `extension.ts`/`extension.js` file.**

There, you can put the code for, for example, launching a specific `Command`, or creating a specific `Tree View`.

Hope it helps.